# Postgres pgAdmin: backup not saving any file on osx

Tags: macos, postgresql, pgadmin, pgagent

Using postgres 9.5.5 on osx Sierra 10.12.1

The database & pgAdmin 4 (version 1.1) work fine, but when trying to save tables or take backups from pgAdmin (selecting data: YES), nothing is saved. The files are just not created.

The only feedback on screen is a small popup "Import/Export job created" or "Backup job created". Then nothing seems to happen. Nothing is saved at all.

The postgres log says 'schema "pgagent" does not exist'

Is pgagent required for this to work?

Comment: Does it work if you run `pg_dump` manually?

Comment: yes, pg_dmp works fine.  But in the dumped file it says: pg_dump version 9.6.1. So maybe there is a version conflict. I installed postgres 9.6 a while ago but stepped back to 9.5 due some issues with 9.6

Comment: Tried pgAdmin 3 and... it works.  For some reason pgAdmin 4 doesn't show the options to select the objects to backup, it only shows General & Dump options.  pgAdmin 3 shows these additional tabs: Dump options 2, Objects & Messages.